# Unauthorized ERROR for Twilio API using RCurl

Tags: r, twilio, rcurl

I am trying to use httpPOST (RCurl Package in R) message to send sms using Twilio API. Getting unauthorized error.

```
httpPOST(url ="https://{sid}:{auth_token}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{sid}/Messages",Body = "HI",From = "+15042520074", To = "+658XXX")
```

I don't want to use the devtools::RTwilio wrapper for Twilio in R.

Can you pls tell me why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

It seems you're not declaring your request as `Basic Authentication.` Not doing so will give you the `Unauthorized Error`.

Try changing your request to look more like:

```
 options(RCurlOptions = list(
 cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"),
 httpauth=AUTH_BASIC
)
)

the_url <- paste("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/",{sid},"/Messages.XML",sep="")
postForm(the_url,
         .opts = list(
           userpwd = paste({sid},":",{auth_token},sep=""),
           useragent = "RCurl",
           verbose = TRUE
         ),
         .params = c(From = "+15042520074", 
                     To = "+658XXX", 
                     Body = "Hi" 
         )
)
```

More information about this on [this website](https://dreamtolearn.com//ryan/data_analytics_viz/80).

Comment: Thanks.But this is giving me the SSL Cert problem.                                            * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 174.129.249.176...
*   Trying 54.243.116.242...
* Connected to api.twilio.com (174.129.249.176) port 443 (#0)
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
* Closing connection 0
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: The equivalent httr code is a bit cleaner: https://gist.github.com/hadley/e6aadb2df97fc1a1e271